# Accuracy goes to 0.0000 when training RNN with Keras?

Tags: keras

I'm trying to use custom word-embeddings from Spacy for training a sequence -> label RNN query classifier. Here's my code:

```
word_vector_length = 300
dictionary_size = v.num_tokens + 1
word_vectors = v.get_word_vector_dictionary()
embedding_weights = np.zeros((dictionary_size, word_vector_length))
max_length = 186
for word, index in dictionary._get_raw_id_to_token().items():
    if word in word_vectors:
        embedding_weights[index,:] = word_vectors[word]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=dictionary_size, output_dim=word_vector_length,
                    input_length= max_length, mask_zero=True, weights=[embedding_weights]))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, activation= 'relu', return_sequences=False)))
model.add(Dense(v.num_labels, activation= 'sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer = 'adam',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=200, nb_epoch=20)
```

here the word_vectors are stripped from spacy.vectors and have length 300, the input is an `np_array` which looks like `[0,0,12,15,0...]` of dimension 186, where the integers are the token ids in the input, and I've constructed the embedded weight matrix accordingly. The output layer is `[0,0,1,0,...0]` of length 26 for each training sample, indicating the label that should go with this piece of vectorized text.

This looks like it should work, but during the first epoch the training accuracy is continually decreasing... and by the end of the first epoch/for the rest of training, it's exactly 0 and I'm not sure why this is happening. I've trained plenty of models with keras/TF before and never encountered this issue.

Any idea what might be happening here?

Comment: Have you tried decreasing the learning rate? The default `1e-3` for adam is pretty high for this task.

Answer (score -1):

Are the labels always one-hot? Meaning only one of the elements of the label vector is one and the rest zero.

If so, then maybe try using a softmax activation with a categorical crossentropy loss like in the following official example:

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/babi_memnn.py#L202

This will help constraint the network to output probability distributions on the last layer (i.e. the softmax layer outputs sum up to 1).